# My wifi is not showing/Network unclaimed

Tags: wireless

Actually, my WiFi was not working when I connected a Bluetooth device. So to solve it I ran this command:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=111n_disable=8bt_coex_active=1power_save=0 swcrypto=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf > /dev/null
```

and rebooted.

Now my WiFi is gone.
When I run:

```
sudo -lshw -c network
```

it showed "network unclaimed" for WiFi. But my Ethernet and Bluetooth are working fine

I tried to include a screenshot but an error occurred while adding a picture here.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: We need to see the output of `sudo lshw -c Network`.  Copy the text from it, put it into a pastebin, and then put a link to that pastebin here.

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/4b8a6809

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Reboot as your command as written is wrong

Comment: It worked like a magic. Thank you